# Filter products by "Tax class"

Tags: admin, attributes, catalog, tax, filter

Is there a way in the admin panel to filter products by some weird attribute such as "tax class"?

The only way I found 'till now is:

```
select distinct value `product name` 
from catalog_product_entity_varchar n 
join catalog_product_index_price p on n.entity_id = p.entity_id 
join eav_attribute a on a.attribute_id = n.attribute_id  and a.attribute_code = 'name'
join tax_class t on t.class_id = p.tax_class_id
where class_name = 'Integratori'
```

Obviously this filters only on the "tax class name" attribute and lacks of a "user friedly" interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add more filterable columns to the product grid, you need to rewrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` class, add the column in `_prepareColumns()` and join the attribute in  `_prepareCollection()`.

There are a number of "(extended|advanced|enhanced) product grid" extensions, that let you configure the grid columns without writing custom code.